# Magento 2 Contact From Create Attachment files and attachment data not received Emails

Tags: magento2, contact-form

Contact us from I have created the Attachment file upload and showing the contact us from Please Check

[image]

But In email Not received the attachment files but only received file name Please Check

[image]

And I have made the admin side Email Templates use

[image]
How to get the file attachment data in the email using admin panel Email templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using 2.3.2 or earlier my extension should work

https://github.com/DominicWatts/ContactAttachment

I've confirmed v1.0.4 works

If you are using 2.3.3 or later you might have issue

Use v1.0.6

I haven't been able to test 2.3.3 or later in live environment yet